# LIBOR and fixed income

Tags: debt, fixed-income

So I am just learning about fixed-income markets and securities, and LIBOR pops up all the time.

Why are interbank offered rates used as reference rates in floating-rate debt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the very short term rate of the very highest credit quality borrowers. Hence it will be the lowest rate available since rates rise with duration and lower credit quality. So if you know the duration and credit quality of a floating loan, you can say that it is +1.05% for duration and +2.35% for credit quality and get that the rate is LIBOR +3.40%. Since there will be no lower rate, it makes a good starting point.